# IF statement not working in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

i'm trying to get this program to work: I have 2 lists "a" and "b", I have to type in a word that appears in both lists which in this case is "cat", but it does not accept cat and says it is wrong. Please help!

```
a=['bird', 'cat', 'dog']
b=['cat', 'mouse','hamster']
print(a,b)
same=(set(a) & set(b))


guess=input("what word is the same in both lists ?")
if guess=='same':
    print ("well done")
else:
    print ("wrong")
```

Comment: you are checking if the input result was 'same'. You probably typed cat, which resulted in the string 'cat'. 'cat' == 'same' is False.

Comment: Hi guess is a variable for when user types in a response such as "cat" or "dog", so user will see what word occurs in both lists and enter it. Each time I type in the word that occurs it does not accept.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to check if the string `guess` is an element of the set `same`.  If that is what you're trying to do, you should use the `in` operator like this:

```
if guess in same:
    print ("well done")
else:
    print ("wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

`set(a) & set(b)` returns a set with one element, but you are comparing `guess` to a string.  You don't want to see if the user typed in `"same"`, you want to see if what he typed in is the string inside the set `same`.  One possibility is to do `if set([guess]) == same`.

Also, if you are using Python 2, you should use `raw_input` instead of `input` to get the input as a string.

Answer (score 0):

don't check equality on string "same", but on variable name same.  Also, 'same' is a set, so to check if guess is in that set use `if guess in same:`